# How do I sync MS Access and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access, synchronization, synchronize

I have Access database that is populated with data from measure machines. I need to get data to MySQL database.
Can I synchronize MS Access and MySQL databases every 3 minutes?

Can someone recommend or point to right direction?

Comment: See [Exporting Access Data to MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access-export.html).

Comment: Yes, but how to synchronize in real-time?

Comment: A similar question, have you looked at this answer? [Synchronizing Access DB and MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3080793/6668133)